# EhCache CacheManager with multiple EntityManagerFactory

Tags: spring, ehcache, entitymanager

And one entityManagerFactory in spring-server.xml.

But i must generate one more entityManager, and i do it with

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myotherpersistenceunitname");
```

but i get exception

```
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name.
The source of the existing CacheManager is: DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ]
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.assertNoCacheManagerExistsWithSameName(CacheManager.java:457)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:354)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:242)
    at net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory.start(EhCacheRegionFactory.java:70)
```

spring.xml:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="merve.web.app" >
     <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation" />
    </context:component-scan>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" proxy-target-class="true"  />

    <cache:annotation-driven />


    <bean id="properties" class="merve.web.app.configuration.PropertyResourceConfiguration" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"  
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">  
         <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPU"/>  
         <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
         <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">  
             <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">  
                 <property name="databasePlatform" value="${database.target}"/>  
                 <property name="showSql" value="${database.showSql}" />  
             </bean>
         </property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driver}"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="2"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10"/>
        <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false"/>
        <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="3"/>
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="300" />
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="jamesEntityManagerFactory"  
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">  
         <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jamesPU"/>  
         <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceJames" />
         <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/james-persistence.xml"/> 
         <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">  
             <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">  
                 <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>  
                 <property name="showSql" value="true" />  
             </bean>
         </property>   
    </bean>  



    <bean id="dataSourceJames" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:derby:../var/store/derby;create=true"/>
        <property name="user" value="app"/>
        <property name="password" value="app"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="2"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10"/>
        <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false"/>
        <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="3"/>
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="300" />
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


     <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">  
        <property name="basenames">  
            <list>
                <value>messages</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Ehcache library setup -->
    <bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:shared="true" p:config-location="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>

    <bean id="cacheManager"   class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" >
     <property name="cacheManager"><ref local="ehcache"></ref></property>  
    </bean>

<dwr:configuration/>
    <dwr:annotation-scan base-package="tuxi.web.app.service.dwr" scanRemoteProxy="true" scanDataTransferObject="true"/>
    <dwr:url-mapping />

    <dwr:controller id="dwrController"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: Can you post your configuration files? I expect that you can make 2 cache managers with different names.

Comment: @mael i added spring.xml. how can i set names to cache maangers, i only can set ids for now. also should i tell entityManagerFactories to use which cache manager

Answer (score 2):

The problem, described [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-31-caching-and-ehcache), and fixed in [the source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/a9605a11e98d2b1f225aca1b5989c41a6b231cf8/spring-context-support/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/ehcache/EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.java#L150) is not using the EhCache singleton correctly.  The answer depends on which version of `spring-context-support` AND which version of EhCache you are using.  For both, you need to be using **EhCache 2.6 or greater**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Next, determine what to do based on your `spring-context-support` version:

### If using Spring 3.1/3.2

```
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
    p:shared="true" 
    p:config-location="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
```

### If using Spring 4.x

```
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
    p:shared="false"
    P:acceptExisting="true" 
    p:config-location="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try naming both cacheManagers differently in ehcache.xml

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    name="ehCacheManager1">

<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    name="ehCacheManager2">
```